# Should the Stack Overflow app show other SE achievements?

Tags: discussion, bug, android-app

The new Stack Overflow app has an Achievements panel, which, of course, makes perfect sense. However, I'm puzzled by the fact that it shows achievements gained in any SE site, not just SO. E.g.:

[image: Achievements from SO, SU and Open Source Beta]

This is the only place in the app the acknowledges the other SE sites. Clicking through a rep gain that isn't on SO opens the relevant question on the old Stack Exchange app. While this kind of makes sense, and is consistent with the top bar when visiting SO on a desktop browser, it's still a bit weird - it opens a different app, and there's no sensible way to click back to where you came from (except for switching apps, unlike, e.g., pressing the "back" button on your browser).

I wonder if the Stack Overflow app should remain dedicated to Stack Overflow, and not show achievements from other sites.

Technical details:

- App version: 1.0.1
- Android version: 5.1.1
- Phone Model: Nexus 4

Comment: Should the inbox and achivements popups only show you Stack Overflow related items when on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Oded No. But that's in a browser, which can display any kind of sites. This question is about an app which is designed to show Stack Overflow content only.

Comment: @Gerry - the inbox and achivements have been designed to show network wide content. I don't know that it is essential to close out the rest of the network from the app - what harm does it do?

Comment: @Oded while it isn't necessarily "harmful" it sure makes for a confusing UX

Comment: I don't want to see non SO-content in my SO-exclusive app. Definitely a bug, if only UX.

Comment: Even in a browser I sometimes wish I weren't bothered with updates from other SE sites.

Comment: @Oded My point was the "odd" UX this creates ("it opens a different app, and there's no sensible way to click back to where you came from (except for switching apps, unlike, e.g., pressing the "back" button on your browser)"). As seen in the comments, and their upvotes, this opinion is shared by others as well.

Comment: @Oded For the network-wide inbox there's already the complete Stack Exchange app. If everything goes this way, the SO app will be.... possible duplicate of Stack Exchange app.